# Parent task not waiting for Child task

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, wait

First of, I 'm very new to threads. What I'm trying to accomplish is that, there is a list of urls, which I'm trying to crawl(I think) and detect flash if the url has it, and that too parallelly. Some urls have external links which means I have to spawn a new task and call my method recursively. I wanted to use AsParallel or Parallel.ForEach, but they don't take Task inputs.

So I have 2 problems. 
1) I want a better approach to parallelly crawl through urls(recursively if needed)
2) If what I have written is a good approach, then what should I do so a task waits for its child?

P.S. I have searched stackoverflow, and couldn't find what I needed. Sorry if I missed questions where someone has already answered similar to mine.

```
    async Task CrawlAndDetectFlash(LearningResource resource, string url, int depth)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var response = await client.GetAsync(url))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            using (var content = response.Content)
            {
                var result = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                resource.FlashRequired = result.Contains("application/x-shockwave-flash") || result.Contains("application/x-director") || result.Contains(".swf") ? 1 : 0;
                if (resource.FlashRequired == 0 && depth == 1)
                {
                    var document = new HtmlDocument();
                    document.LoadHtml(result);
                    var links = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
                        .Where(a => a.Attributes.Contains("class") && String.Equals(a.GetAttributeValue("class", string.Empty), "external"))
                        .Select(a => a.GetAttributeValue("href", null))
                        .Distinct()
                        .Where(u => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(u))
                        .ToList();
                    if (links.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var link in links)
                        {
                            Task child = CrawlAndDetectFlash(resource, link, 2);
                            child.Wait();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to distinguish between "concurrency", "parallelism", and "asynchrony". Concurrency is doing more than one thing at a time; parallelism is a form of concurrency using multiple threads; and asynchrony is a form of concurrency without threads. Parallelism is best for CPU-bound code when you want to spread threads across several CPU cores. Asynchrony is best for I/O-bound code when you don't want to block threads.

In your case, it looks like you're primarily I/O-bound, so asynchrony is the way to go. This means that `AsParallel` and `Parallel.ForEach` are improper solutions for this problem (they're parallel, not asynchronous).

The next lesson (as I describe on my blog) is that you [don't want to block on asynchronous code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html); blocking defeats the entire point of asynchrony. So `Task<T>.Result` and `Task.Wait` should not be used. Instead of these, just use `await`:

```
async Task CrawlAndDetectFlashAsync(LearningResource resource, string url, int depth)
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  using (var response = await client.GetAsync(url))
  {
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    using (var content = response.Content)
    {
      var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // Result -> await
      resource.FlashRequired = result.Contains("application/x-shockwave-flash") || result.Contains("application/x-director") || result.Contains(".swf") ? 1 : 0;
      if (resource.FlashRequired == 0 && depth == 1)
      {
        var document = new HtmlDocument();
        document.LoadHtml(result);
        var links = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
                    .Where(a => a.Attributes.Contains("class") && String.Equals(a.GetAttributeValue("class", string.Empty), "external"))
                    .Select(a => a.GetAttributeValue("href", null))
                    .Distinct()
                    .Where(u => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(u))
                    .ToList();
        if (links.Count > 0)
        {
          foreach (var link in links)
          {
            Task child = CrawlAndDetectFlashAsync(resource, link, 2);
            await child; // Wait -> await
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now that the method is properly asynchronous, you can look into adding more concurrency. E.g., if you want to process all child links concurrently, the `foreach` loop can be rewritten as:

```
if (links.Count > 0)
{
  var childTasks = links.Select(x => CrawlAndDetectFlashAsync(resource, x, 2)).ToList();
  await Task.WhenAll(childTasks);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your code like this

```
List<Task> children = new List<Task>();
foreach (var link in links)
{
    Task child = CrawlAndDetectFlash(resource, link, 2);
    children.Add(child);
}

Task.WaitAll(children.ToArray());
```